# Add validation to numbers stored as text in Access

Tags: ms-access

Field name in MS Access table - s1
data type - text

I use this field to store student marks.

'AA' will be entered if the student is absent and therefore I have selected text data type for this field

I want to restrict data entry to minimum marks = 0 and maximum = 75

How do I enter validation rule in this text field?

Comment: please see this link  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Restrict-data-input-by-using-a-validation-rule-63c8f07a-6dad-4fbd-9fef-5c6616e7fbfd?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set maximum length of the text of the field to: 2

Set validation rule to: "AA" Or Between "00" And "75"

Also, apply an *inputmask* to force two characters, or make sure that values between 0 and 9 are entered as 00 and 09.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to reconsider your decision to store the values as Text. You could store them as Numeric and just use a custom `Format` property to display `AA` when the value is Null (which is allowed when "Required=No"):

[image: Untitled.png]

Answer (score 0):

In design view for your table that will store the student mark, select the student mark field.

In the field properties in the lower part of the screen set the *Field Size* to `2`, the *Validation Rule* to `"AA" Or Between "0" And "75"` and then in the *Validation Text* field, write a helpful message to the user describing the valid data they can enter in to this field:

[image]

If the user tries to put in data outside the restrictions of your validation rule, they'll see your validation text message and won't be able to save their invalid data:

[image]

Comment: That will also accept many large numbers. You must limit the entry length to two.